# Does the Earth's core have tides?

Tags: earth, geophysics, tidal-effect

Does the moon produce a measurable tidal-effect on the Earth's (liquid) core? If so, how strong is it? Would it play a factor in other geological effects like earthquakes, volcanoes, etc?

Comment: this gives a review  http://geography.about.com/od/physicalgeography/a/Land-Tides-Or-Earth-Tides.htm and then gives a link for further reading  http://geography.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=geography&cdn=education&tm=221&f=00&su=p284.13.342.ip_&tt=2&bt=8&bts=8&zu=http%3A//www.gps.caltech.edu/classes/ge167/file/agnew_treat_tide.pdf

Comment: I didn't know of the term 'land tide'. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gravitational fields of the Sun and the Moon do produce measurable effects on the shape of the Earth. The tidal distortion of the solid Earth (and the liquid outer core) is often referred to as the [Earth Tide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_tide) to distinguish it from ocean tides.

The gravitational effects of the Earth tide do cause small strains in the Earth which  might influence geophysical processes such as volcanic eruptions and earthquakes - however, it is hard to prove specific cause and effect instances.

This paper: [Earth Tides](http://booksite.elsevier.com/brochures/geophysics/PDFs/00056.pdf) provides a detailed explanation of Earth tide physics and this [figure](http://www.okgeosurvey1.gov/tide.html)  provides an example of measurements.

Agnew, D. C. (2007). Earth Tides, pp. 163-195 in *Treatise on Geophysics: Geodesy*, T. A. Herring, ed., Elsevier, New York.

Comment: Can you find a new link for your "Earth Tides" paper: this one is broken. Would you kindly please give a full citation of the paper, so that it can be found if the link breaks again.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Based on finding it at archive.org this seems to be a textbook chapter (it has section numbers starting with 3.06 and page numbers starting with 163) of [this book](http://store.elsevier.com/product.jsp?isbn=9780444519283).

Answer (score 3):

According to https://lockhaven.edu/~dsimanek/scenario/tides.htm, the earth crust moves about 20 cm in response to tidal forces. I expect that if stress is built up in a fault line, this would play a part in releasing it, but this is not my area of expertise.